# How to interpret G1 GC logs leading up to an OutOfMemoryError?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm, g1gc

I was wondering if someone is able to explain to me how to interpret some G1 GC logs that lead up to an OutOfMemoryError?

I know that a heap dump is the best bet for finding out what is actually using the heap but I can't get that since it contains protected information that cannot leave the client site. All I have are the application logs (which include the stack from the OOME) and the G1 GC logs.

The full G1 GC logs have a lot of detail so I won't put them here unless someone specifically needs to see them.

The specific Java version that these came from was:

```
> java -version
java version "1.7.0_21"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_21-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.21-b01, mixed mode)
```

And the GC options I am using to create the GC log are:

```
-XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps
-XX:+PrintGCDetails
-Xloggc:log/gc.log
```

Below are all the memory stats from each young and full GC during the last 30 minutes leading up to the OOME:

```
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/05/28 04:29:34 | [Eden: 1290M(1290M)->0B(1290M) Survivors: 20M->20M Heap: 2445M(3932M)->1155M(3932M)]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/05/28 04:33:21 | [Eden: 1290M(1290M)->0B(1290M) Survivors: 20M->20M Heap: 2445M(3932M)->1155M(3932M)]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/05/28 04:37:09 | [Eden: 1290M(1290M)->0B(1290M) Survivors: 20M->20M Heap: 2445M(3932M)->1155M(3932M)]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/05/28 04:40:58 | [Eden: 1290M(1290M)->0B(1290M) Survivors: 20M->20M Heap: 2445M(3932M)->1155M(3932M)]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/05/28 04:44:44 | [Eden: 1290M(1290M)->0B(1290M) Survivors: 20M->20M Heap: 2445M(3932M)->1155M(3932M)]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/05/28 04:48:30 | [Eden: 1290M(1290M)->0B(1290M) Survivors: 20M->20M Heap: 2445M(3932M)->1155M(3932M)]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/05/28 04:52:17 | [Eden: 1290M(1290M)->0B(1290M) Survivors: 20M->20M Heap: 2445M(3932M)->1155M(3932M)]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/05/28 04:52:58 | [Eden: 639M(1290M)->0B(1295M) Survivors: 20M->15M Heap: 2278M(3932M)->1635M(3932M)]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/05/28 04:52:59 | [Eden: 51M(1295M)->0B(1300M) Survivors: 15M->10M Heap: 2561M(3932M)->2505M(3932M)]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/05/28 04:52:59 | [Full GC 2505M->1170M(3901M), 1.9469560 secs]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/05/28 04:53:01 | [Eden: 44M(1300M)->0B(1299M) Survivors: 0B->1024K Heap: 1653M(3901M)->1610M(3901M)]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/05/28 04:53:01 | [Eden: 1024K(1299M)->0B(1299M) Survivors: 1024K->1024K Heap: 1610M(3901M)->1610M(3901M)]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/05/28 04:53:02 | [Full GC 1610M->1158M(3891M), 1.4317370 secs]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/05/28 04:53:03 | [Eden: 112M(1299M)->0B(1296M) Survivors: 0B->1024K Heap: 1758M(3891M)->1647M(3891M)]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/05/28 04:53:06 | [Eden: 49M(1296M)->0B(1360M) Survivors: 1024K->1024K Heap: 2776M(4084M)->2728M(4084M)]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/05/28 04:53:06 | [Eden: 0B(1360M)->0B(1360M) Survivors: 1024K->1024K Heap: 2837M(4084M)->2836M(4084M)]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/05/28 04:53:06 | [Full GC 2836M->1158M(3891M), 1.4847750 secs]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/05/28 04:53:08 | [Full GC 1158M->1158M(3891M), 1.5313770 secs]
```

* This is a different format to the raw logs and I removed the timing details to make it shorter and easier to read.

I also graphed the raw GC logs these in GCViewer:

[image]

It seems like everything was going ok so far:

- The used tenured was constant (the dark magenta line at the bottom of the graph).
- Young GC pauses occurred every couple of minutes cleaning up all the young objects (the grey line at the top of the graph).
- Allocated sizes for each generation were constant.
- Heap usage after the young GCs was around 1155M.

Then at `2015/05/28 04:52:59` things went pear shaped:

- The tenured all of a sudden started growing.
- When the young GC ran there were only 51M in the eden space.
- Full GCs started occurring.
- The first 3 full GCs seemed ok, they reduced the heap usage to 1158M-1170M (which is very close to the normal 1155M).
- The final full GC started with 1158M used and was still 1158M after.

The Memory tab in the screenshot shows:

```
Tenured heap (usage / alloc. max)    2,836 (104.1%) / 2,723M
Total promotion                                       2,048K
```

Now to explain briefly what occurred at `2015/05/28 04:52:59`. At this point a whole bunch of configuration objects were serialised to a custom format using a StringBuilder. This resulted in a bunch of array copies which eventually resulted in the following exception at `2015/05/28 04:53:09`:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2367)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity(AbstractStringBuilder.java:130)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(AbstractStringBuilder.java:114)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:587)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:214)
    ...
```

There are a few things I can't explain:

1. Where in the GC logs would you find the used tenured memory?
2. What would cause such a significant spike in the used tenured memory to cause a GC? There were only 20M of survivors so wouldn't in the worst case these all go to tenured and no more?
3. Could this perhaps be explained by a humongous object allocation?
4. Why was the last full GC triggered when there was (apparently) so little used heap and at afterwards it cleaned up nothing?
5. If there was 3891M heap allocated and only 1158M used then why would there be an OOME?

Comment: You should run with `-XX:+PrintGCDetails` for additional information that GCViewer can process

Comment: @the8472 Yup that's what I have done. I have added those details to the question.

Comment: I am going to try with the `-XX:+PrintAdaptiveSizePolicy` option to see if it shows a humongous object allocation.

Comment: Well, I don't recall about java7, but in java8 gc logs show a *reason* what triggered the GC, i'm not seeing that in your logs. Failures to allocate humongous objects usually cause a last-ditch GC before the OOME and print that in the logs. But those are fairly easy to spot anyway because they usually throw always at the same spot, most applications don't have many callsites that cause huge allocations.

Comment: The option for the cause: `-XX:+PrintGCCause`. you probably should pastebin the full log somewhere so we can have a look at it.

Comment: Probably useful also to put a log line in your application printing out the number of objects you are serializing each time, so you can see if there is something strange when the problem happens. Other useful thing is to grab a heap dump (if possible) and open it with Memory Analyser Tool: it will show all the objects in memory with the reference tree and default analysis for memory leaks

Answer (score 1):

Your out of memory happens during StringBuilder.append - bear in mind that every time you append a string and the buffer inside the StringBuilder is too small such that it expands the capacity, it will try to allocate dobule the buffer by double the current length of the String in the builder plus 2 or the new length if bigger . (See source code for [AbstractStringBuilder.java](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/AbstractStringBuilder.java.html))

For example, if your string builder already has 100 characters and is full, then you append another 10 characters to it, it will expand by:

100*2+2 = 202, which is more than 10.

So if you already have a really long string (10MB), it will attempt to create a 20MB buffer and so on.

Check you code and make sure you are not creating huge strings in the builder.